# openVPN client configuration of ip address

Tags: 18.04, dns, vpn, openvpn, client

I am confused with regard to the correct ip address to use when a remote client tries to connect to the server running on Ubuntu 18.04. Details of ip's on the server:

openVPN server 10.8.0.1

port 1194

Ubuntu eno1  IPv4 10.0.0.3 public ip is from the netgear router

Netgear router dynamic ip.

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com gives 105.226.251.32 which changes.
```

It seems to me I should use a dns to obtain the public IP but will this then connect to 10.8.0.1?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! Could you specify your network configurations, please? What is your `lan` ip-range, what is the network that `openVPN` routes its clients to? It seems to me that you mix up these private IP-ranges (designated by your router i.e. dhcp) with your public IP that is provided by your ISP.
Further. you have to create a firewall rule that routs port 1194 from your router to your openVPN-server.

Comment: Thanks for answering

My network consists  of only an Ubuntu server with a Netgear ADSL router I have an openVPN server running on this machine.

 All clients(5) will access the the vpn server (and the Ubuntu data server) remotely using their own routers and internet
If I run myipadress it shows the dynamic ip provided by my ISP.
My client config files are setup with a DNS entry which gets the correct current IP of the router.
Everything works right up to the handshake stage.
The firewall allows 1194.
I think my problem must be the link between the netgear and the the VPN server.

Comment: Can you confirm that your router's firewall has an open port 1194 and that this port is routed to your openVPN server via NAT? Did you set the correct firewall rules for your networks (10.0.0.0/24 and 10.8.0.0/24)?

Comment: I have not set the router NAT!! that must be the problem - not sure how to do this but will figure it out.
I will check the firewall again but i am sure I did do those.

Thanks a lot will let you know how it goes

Comment: Have checked all on client side but I now see this error:
$     tail -100 /var/log/syslog gives an error

 Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: /etc/openvpn/server.conf
So I seem to have a problem on my server set-up. Possibly because of setting-up server 2 then deleting files

Answer (score 2):

In the end the answer was simple - my lack of knowledge on networking!
All that was required was to set-up port forwarding on the DSL router - in my case I am using an old Netgear router - so I had to set-up a service for the port (1194) and then change the firewall rules to allow that service. 
It should be easier on a more modern Router